# GWT Client files in one Server & GWT Servlets in other Server

Tags: gwt

I'm trying to separate GWT Client & Server. If i'm not wrong, GWT client code is getting server reponses by connecting to the servlet we mentioned in GWT Project's web.xml. If So, can i host my GWT Servlets in one Tomcat Server & GWT Client code in other tomcat server ..?

Will it work ..?  If so how to do that, i have already tried something working with hosted.html in GWT Client files. But it didn't worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same question has been asked in the past.

[gwt-split-client-and-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240848/gwt-split-client-and-server-to-different-machines)

What you can do is use the servlet as a proxy to another server, where you have implemented your model logic.

Comment: Sorry i have checked on other stackoverflow posts before posting this question, but that didn't popped up. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can host client files in any web-server since they are static stuff, actually what you need is to pick your index.html, the .nocache.js and all the *.cache.(js|html) files and put them in any web server (apache, nginx, iis, jetty, etc).

You could even replace the index.html by any other html generator like php, jsp etc.

But of course the server side should be hosted in a servlet container.

What you have to be aware about, is that when the server with your static files are in a different domain than the servlet server, ajax requests will fail because of security constrains (see CORS).

To avoid that restriction there are many ways in gwt (gwtquery-jsonp, gwt-xdm, etc).

What I'm using is a filter (see code above) able to enable CORS when an options request is received.

You have to modify your client code as well to configure correctly the url of the servlet-container. Here is an example for changing the url with RequestFactory.

Client side code for RF:

```
myFactory = GWT.create(MyRFFactory.class);
DefaultRequestTransport transport = new DefaultRequestTransport();
transport.setRequestUrl("http://my.servletcontainer.com/gwtRequest");
myFactory.initialize(eventBus, transport);
```

web.xml configuration

```
   <filter>
   <filter-name>CORSFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>my.namespace.CORSFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>CORSFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Server filter

```
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest,
      ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

    String o = req.getHeader("Origin");
    if ("options".equalsIgnoreCase(req.getMethod())) {
      resp.setHeader("Allow", "GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS");
      if (o != null) {
        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", o);
        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", 
                       "POST, GET, OPTIONS");
        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                       "content-type,pageurl,x-gwt-permutation");
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
      }
      resp.getWriter().flush();
      return;
    }

    if (o != null) {
      resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", o);
    }

    if (filterChain != null) {
      filterChain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }
  }

  @Override public void destroy() {
  }

  @Override public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
  }

}
```

Comment: What is eventBus in this example?  I'm looking to do something similar, and this sample code might be just what I'm looking for.

Comment: Request factory(RF) needs a gwt eventbus instance to work, normally it is shared by all the gwt app and this is the reason why RF initialization needs it. In this case EventBus eventBus = new SimpleEventBus();